# Rename files based on a list

Tags: r, bash, list, rename

I would like to rename all files in a folder based on a text file (`list.txt`) with two columns: `oldnam` (which represents the current name) and `newnam` (which contains the required new name).

My text file:

```
df <- "oldnam newnam
       TRTY_3.DOT 124325.DOT
       TRTY_4.DOT 123454.DOT
       TRTY_5.DOT 124355.DOT"
df <- read.table(text=df, header=T)
write.table(df, "list.txt", col.names=T, row.names=F, quote=F)
```

It is possible to do it from R or directly in bash (both solutions could help a lot)?

Comment: yes, `?file.rename`. Also, what did you try already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First list the files in your folder

```
file.list <- list.files(yourfolderpath,  pattern="\\.DOT$", full.names=TRUE)
```

Then use file.rename to rename files based on your list.txt file.

```
   file.rename(from = file.path(dirname(file.list), list.txt$oldnam), to  = file.path(dirname(file.list), list.txt$newnam))
```

Answer (score 1):

initial files in folder

```
 ll
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Jan 15 18:01 1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Jan 15 18:01 2.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Jan 15 18:01 3.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Jan 15 18:01 4.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Jan 15 18:01 5.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  40 Jan 15 18:01 files
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 272 Jan 15 18:10 script.sh
```

list of files

```
cat files
1.txt 11.txt
2.txt 22.txt
3.txt 33.txt
```

running the script

```
./script.sh files
root@xx:~#
```

files in folder after running script

```
 ll
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Jan 15 18:01 11.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Jan 15 18:01 22.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Jan 15 18:01 33.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Jan 15 18:01 4.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Jan 15 18:01 5.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  40 Jan 15 18:01 files
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 270 Jan 15 18:11 script.sh
```

the script

```
cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash
filename="$1"
folder_with_files=/root/

while read -r line
do
oldname=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $1}')
newname=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $2}')
[ -z "$oldname" ] && { break ; }
mv  $folder_with_files$oldname $folder_with_files$newname
done < "$filename"
```